# How to Stop a VCs functions from operating when VC is not in view? [Swift 3.0 Xcode]

Tags: swift, xcode, function, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller which contains functions wish I need to disable once I leave the view controller. The functions wont start until I navigate to the VC, which is what I want, but I also what these functions to stop once I leave and navigate to other view controllers. Does anyone know any tricks to this?

Comment: What are these functions?  Are they timer-related?  You can invalidate any timers in `viewWillDisappear`

Comment: Its a function that updates a users location

Comment: You can call `stopUpdatingLocation` in `viewWillDisappear`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are multiple ways you can do this. 
One like others have commented is invalidate timers or location stuff in either one of these methods.

```
 let someTimer = Timer()

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    someTimer.invalidate()
}
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    someTimer.invalidate()
}
```